# Weird issue with last product image change in odoov13

Tags: javascript, html, odoo

I have this code in javascript to change the product image on mouse over. It is working fine, but only for two first products. Last one is being ignored.

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-oe-id] img');

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    let image = list[i];
    let src = image.src;

    image.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
      console.log(src);
      image.src = "https://media1.giphy.com/media/PfFtibPKBbQrK/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47b668e5062e9a561e681f23705e106d8d495b3915&rid=giphy.gif";
    });

    image.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) {
      image.src = src;
    });
}
```

Here is the video of an issue - [Video Source](https://mega.nz/file/aRUziACJ#bwTlV1wWd_P3kyqYARikyJC-o8hVszJikE_NDaM-jkw)

I think that it is very weird, because only the last product is being ignored, and yes, I have tried to do `list.length + 1` in the loop, but had no luck with it. All the products have the same HTML structure. Here is the resulting HTML code of a product view in show - [Pastebin Source](https://pastebin.com/KPFuGnWA)

Speaking about my templates code, there's nothing special, just an xpath for card and oe_product_cart classes

Comment: Please consider adding a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Daan Do you want me to post a vdi image from virtualbox? xD

Comment: I suggest adding the necessary HTML to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Daan Here it is - https://pastebin.com/dbY8P63N Code of all page

Comment: Please read the article I linked earlier to try and create a Minimal, Reproducible example. Making it minimal would make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: I could cut some code, but I am not sure that it will not affect the problem

Comment: Try cutting off parts of code that you think aren't necessary. Check if the problem is still reproducible. Otherwise, revert removing it. This way you will end up with a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It might even help you understand the problem yourself. And otherwise makes it easier for other people to spot your problem. Currently I have no idea what the problem is, you only represented some JavaScript (not HTML). Try adding your code in a code snippet. This helps tremendously.